# transfer html content via $.post in jquery

Tags: jquery, special-characters, .post

how to transfer html content ?
eg:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#actBtn').click(function(){
        var txt = $('#quick_links').html();
        $.post('/services.php','actBtn=save&content=' + txt + '&v=' + Math.random(),function(data){ });
    });
})
```

and in div#quick_links, there are some a links :
http://domain.com?parem=1&time=123345#rw2
 as you saw,  the html content contains some special signs (",#,&), how to deal with them , especial "&" ?

thanks

Comment: Or send the data via a data object so that jquery takes care of that for you. `$.post(url,{ actBtn: "save", content: txt, v: $.now() }, function(){...});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to URLencode your postdata or let jQuery do it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#actBtn').click(function() {
        var txt = $('#quick_links').html();
        $.post('/services.php', {
            actBtn: "save",
            content: txt,
            v: Math.random()
        }, function(data) {});
    });
})
```

Comment: it works, but only problem is the link in data back looks like this: <a href=\"http://domain.com?parem=1&time=123345#rw2\">test</a> how to replace \" to " ?

Comment: @Gideon Turn off [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)

Comment: Note that if you were previously relying on magic quotes to do SQL escaping, your application might be vulnerable now if you are not manually doing `mysql/i_real_escape_string` or prepared statements